# Accessing intermediate class properties in override of template method

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class, `GenericModel`, which defines a template method as follows:

```
public virtual string DoStuff<TType>(IEnumerable<TType> input)
    where TType : GenericModel { return null; }
```

I then have a class that inherits from `GenericModel` called `BasicModel` which represents a certain subset of `GenericModel`'s that have enough in common to warrant another structure. While this is a concrete class, it is never actually instantiated and instead other classes inherit from it, since there are a number of properties in common that aren't necessarily in every `GenericModel` but that are in every `BasicModel` (For example purposes we'll say that every `BasicModel` has an `id` property).

If I have a class that inherits from `BasicModel` called `ChildModel`, and I want to override `DoStuff()`, that is allowed, since `ChildModel` inherits from `BasicModel` which inherits from `GenericModel`. So I define an override  method (in `ChildModel`) as follows:

```
public override string DoStuff<ChildModel>(IEnumerable<ChildModel> input){
    foreach(var data in input){
        var foo = data.id;
        //Do stuff with foo
    }
    //Do more stuff
}
```

The problem is that Visual Studio highlights `data.id` as an error, saying that `data` doesn't have a property named `id`. My assumption is that this is due to the `where TType : GenericModel` part of the template method; it ignores the intermediate `BasicModel` and so I can't access properties defined in `BasicModel`.

This seems odd to me since I'm stating that input *must* consist of `ChildModel`s which will all, by definition as child classes of `BasicModel`, have an `id` property.

Is there a way to access these intermediate class properties in the `ChildModel`'s override of `DoStuff()` or is that impossible with the way I've set up my inheritance? Are there any workarounds or changes I could make to allow use of these properties?

**Edit:** It appears from comments and answers that I have a fundamental misunderstanding of template methods. What I'm really trying to do is define a generic method in the `GenericModel` that takes as input an `IEnumerable<GenericModel>` and then in each child class is overridden, where the override uses an `IEnumerable<ChildClass>` instead. Apparently that goal may not be possible with the structure I have defined.

Comment: In `DoStuff`, `ChildModel` is a type parameter, not a reference to a concrete class. Your method is effecitvely trying to override `DoStuff` with `DoStuff<T>(...)`. You can't specialise generic methods in this way.

Comment: @Lee Doesn't the type parameter define the type of the input parameter with the way I've written it? I thought that the type parameter was simply to allow the input parameter to use a number of different types, one for each of the lowest level classes, where each instance can use all properties of those classes.

Comment: @ChrisH. No, it does not.  You're just giving the generic argument a different name.  It doesn't matter what you call the generic argument, the name in no way changes what it does.

Comment: @Servy Ok, I see what you and Lee are saying now. I guess that leads me to ask how can I (or is it possible) define a method in `GenericModel` that can take an Enumerable of `ChildModel` (or any other child class, defined generically) that will be overridden by each child class using their own class as the type of data in the Enumerable?

Comment: If you want different classes to support different subtypes you should move the type parameter from the method to the class/interface itself e.g. `public interface Doer<TType> where TType : GenericModel`.

Comment: @ChrisH. You can't.  The abstract class defined it as needing to be able to take any type that is a `GenericModel`, so it must fulfill that contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want CastException (@Fabjan answer) you could replace this:

```
var castedInput = input.Cast<BasicModel>();  
foreach (var data in castedInput)
```

with this:

```
foreach (var data in input.OfType<BasicModel>())
```

in that way if you have this example:

```
new ChildModel().DoStuff(new List<GenericModel>
{
   new GenericModel(),
   new BasicModel{id = 2},
   new ChildModel{id = 10},
   new BasicModel{id = 15}
});
```

with DoStuff like this:

```
var foo = data.id;
Console.WriteLine(foo);
```

Your output will be:

```
2
10
15
```

Comment: I'm marking this since it ended up being the one I used, but for future readers; see Lee's answer for more detail on why my initial idea doesn't work or Fabjan's answer for the background for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
public override string DoStuff<ChildModel>(IEnumerable<ChildModel> input) { ... }
```

is not specialising `DoStuff` to only work with `ChildModel`, but is just renaming the `TType` parameter to `ChildModel`. This is equivalent to

```
public override string DoStuff<T>(IEnumerable<T> input) { }
```

this would not compile since you also need to retain the constraint on `TType` from the base class.

The generic constraint on the `DoStuff` method means overrides must handle all subtypes uniformly. It sounds like you want each subclass to support a single particular subtype of `GenericModel`.  In that case you can move the generic parameter to the base class and specify it in each subclass e.g.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TType> where TType : GenericModel {
    public virtual string DoStuff(IEnumerable<TType> input) { ... }
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass<ChildModel> {
    public override string DoStuff(IEnumerable<ChildModel> input) { ... }
}
```

Comment: One question I have about your suggestion is that ultimately I want this method to be called like this: `/*ChildModel*/ childModel.DoStuff(/*IEnumerable<ChildModel>*/ input)`, wheras the way you have it defines a separate `SubClass` that uses an Enumerable of `ChildModel`; I want a `ChildModel` using an Enumerable of `ChildModel`.

Comment: @ChrisH. - Do you mean you want `DoStuff` to be defined on `GenericModel` and each subclass to specify `TType` to be their own concrete type? In that case I suggest you define an interface and do `class ChildModel : IDoStuff<ChildModel>`, although there's no way in the type system to enforce the relationship between the implementing type and parameter provided to `IDoStuff<T>`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do; it's unfortunate that I cannot enforce that relationship. I'll look into that, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Well, with current logic `ChildModel` type parameter can be only of type `GenericModel` as it is not possible to override generic type constraints. 
Because of that - there is no way for compiler to know that we actually pass something convertible to `BasicModel` and that is why we cannot see property 'id'.

To use it as `BasicModel` we can cast the whole collection using `LINQ` :

```
class GenericModel
{
    public virtual string DoStuff<TType>(IEnumerable<TType> input)
        where TType : GenericModel
    {
        return null;
    }
}

class BasicModel : GenericModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}

class ChildModel : BasicModel
{
    public override string DoStuff<TType>(IEnumerable<TType> input)
    {
        var castedInput = input.Cast<BasicModel>();

        foreach (var data in castedInput)
        {
            var foo = data.id;
            //Do stuff with foo
        }
        //Do more stuff

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't override a generic method with a non-generic one.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you mean by "it could be anything" (mabye I'm misunderstanding the use of the type parameter). I was under the impression that in `GenericModel` I set up the type parameter, and in the override in `ChildModel` I create a version of the template method that will be used when an IEnumerable of `ChildModel` is passed in.

Comment: I can't use `where TType : BasicModel` because this template method needs to be availiable for everything that inherits from `GenericModel`, not just the `BasicModel`s.

Comment: I's mistaken. We cannot override generic type constraints. Updated my answer with workaround.

Comment: So with this new logic, what would happen if someone tried to call DoStuff with an input that was of the wrong type? Would it throw an exception?

Comment: Also, with this logic, does `input` in the `ChildModel`'s `DoStuff` still have to inherit `GenericModel`?

Comment: Yes it'll throw an Exception (`InvalidCastException` to be more precise) if cast fails, and again yes input, because of constraint in base `GenericModel` type will still have to inherit from `GenericModel`

Comment: Is there any problem with the `.Cast()` going to `.Cast<ChildModel>` instead? Was there any reason you casted to `BasicModel`?

Comment: @ChrisH. Well, i used `BasicModel` because it will allow method to accept other types that derives from it as well, not necessarily `ChildModel`. But feel free to change it according to your needs.